# JS - changing styling while music is playing

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<audio id="player35" src="tune.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>

<a href="#" onclick="pausePlay(document.getElementById('player35'));" class="music-area">A Tune</a>
```

---

```
.music-area
{
width: 128px;
height: 128px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

background-image: url("img/speaker.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.60);
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

There are a many "playerX" audio tags and associated  that play music when clicked. All of them have class "music-area" so the css above puts a speaker symbol on all of them. I want the speaker to only appear when the music is playing, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `pausePlay` function is executed, you can add another class to the `a` element if starts playing music and remove that class when music stops. Use that new class to style the element.

Comment: `onclick="togglePlay(document.getElementById('player13'), document.getElementById('link13'));"`

`function togglePlay(audelem, linkelem) {
   if (audelem.paused){
    audelem.play();
    linkelem.classList.add("active");
   }else{
    audelem.pause();
    audelem.currentTime = 0;
    linkelem.classList.remove("active");
   }
  }`

I'm pretty new to JS but this seems to have done the trick! thanks.